# No debugging action when I start debugger in VSCode to debug a php file?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

1. I installed the `PHP debug` in VSCode.
2. Overwrote the `php.validate.executablePath`.
3. Downloaded and put the `xdebug.dll` in `/php/ext` and added relevant settings to `php.ini`.
   However,when I tag breakpoints and start XDebug, VSCode has no debugging action.
   Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.Restart the apache service at administrator mode.